# How can I check a game Property?

Tags: game-engine, properties

I need a `bpy.data.objects["object name"]["property value"]` or a command like this.

Comment: Welcome to BSE! If you're new to the StackExchange network, please take the tour:https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour This question does not provide nearly enough information for us to give helpful answers. Please describe what you're trying to do, what you've attempted to achieve that, and what problem you're encountering. This does not _necessarily_ require a lot of words, but it does require _specificity_. Help us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bpy` is the Blender API.

The BGE API is `bge`.

You can access game properties via dictionary access on the game object

## Read

#### Read and fail when it does not exist

```
print("property value is ", gameObject["propertyName"])
```

This is the fastest method, but fails when the property is not present. This is good when the property is mandatory.

#### Read with fallback value

```
print("property value is ", gameObject.get("propertyName", "fallbackValue"))
```

This is pretty fail safe and can be used on optional properties.

Be aware it always creates the fallback value. This costs processing time. Ensure creating the fallback value is fast (or use an existing value).

The property will not be set, when it does not exist.

#### Read with previous existence check:

```
if "propertyName" in gameObject:
    print("property value is ", gameObject["propertyName"])
else:
    print("no property set")
```

Requires more code but is very fail safe. When the property exists the read access is performed twice (once for check existence, once to get the value).

It is good when the property is optional and the fallback situation needs some effort (such as creating larger objects) or leads to complete different behavior. The fallback code will only be executed when the property is not existent. This solution is more efficient when in most of the cases the property is not present (as this results in a single read access).

#### Read with error handling:

```
try:
    print("property value is ", gameObject["propertyName"])
except KeyError:
    print("no property set")
```

More code but fail safe. Pretty efficient as the access will happen just once. The fallback can be complex, it will only be executed when the property is not present.

## Write

```
gameObject["propertyName"] = newValue
```

It is the exact same code, regardless if you want to add or change a property

## Delete

```
del gameObject["propertyName"]
```

## Example

#### Initialize Property

```
try:
    propertyValue = gameObject["propertyName"]
except KeyError:
    propertyValue = "fallbackValue"
    gameObject["propertyName"] = propertyValue 

print("property value is ", propertyValue )
```

[Edit:]

## Getting Game Objects

Just in case you do not know how to get or find game objects:

```
import bge

v1 = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["v1"] # this will fail when there is no object called v1!
farbe = v1.get("farbe")
print("farbe of v1 is", farbe)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my GameObject is "v1" and the propertyName is "farbe"
I tried it with:

import bge

if farbe in v1:
    print("property value is ", v1[farbe])
else:
    print("no property set")

error:

Python script error - object 'v1', controller 'Python':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "property check.py", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'farbe' is not defined

I think it says that farbe isn't a property of v1 but shouldn't come "no property set" then? and actually I have set the Property in the logic bricks ans also tried v1[farbe] = 0 and its still not working

Comment: sorry I don't know how to answer correctly this doesn't seem right.. :/

Comment: oh yeah and when i wrote v1[farbe] = 0 this came:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'v1' is not defined

Comment: The property name is a String. So you need to write v1["farbe"].

Comment: The "NameError" means you used a name that Python does not know what it is. This typically happens when using a variable name before creating this variable as you did. There is no variable, function or keyword called "farbe", but you are using this name. So python does not know what to do and raises the "NameError: name 'farbe' is not defined". As stated above: use the String literal "farbe" (with "). Alternative you could create a variable farbe = "farbe" before using it.

Comment: but I created the variable "farbe" in blender in the logic bricks. It was set a an integer with the value 0 which i wanna change if someting happens in my game. Isn't that enough? Do I have to Set this property by code?

Comment: That is not a variable. it is a property. A property belongs to the game object (you can define and change it via logic bricks). It lives as long as the game object lives. A variable is a named container for a single value within Python. It lives in the code block you created it until there are no references to it anymore. Typically it dies when you leave the function/script

Comment: You want to access the property (via name "farbe) -> gameObject["farbe"]

Comment: Yeah the problem is, my objects name is "v1" and my game property i set to it in the logic bricks is named "farbe" so I simply tried print(v1[farbe]) in the console but then this error came:
"NameError: name 'v1' is not defined" and i dont know why because i definitely have that object.
Same error came when i tried it in the game with a script in the logic bricks.

Comment: The same as before you need to create a variable called "v1" before using it. In your case you should search the scene for a game object of the name "v1". Then you can operate on it. See above.

Comment: I don't get how I can use the game property I set in blender to my object "v1" and even if I completely ignore that and try this code:

import bge

v1=0
v1[farbe] = 10

if farbe in v1:
    print(farbe, v1[farbe])
else:
    print("no property set")

at which i often changed something to try whats wrong it doesn't work and always that comes: NameError: name 'farbe' is not defined.

I also tried just:

import bge

v1["farbe"] = 0

print(v1["farbe"])

but same result.

Sorry i feel like im annoying you, but im really new to this.

Comment: Oh yeah ind I tried this too:

import bge

v1 = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["v1"] # this will fail when there is no object called v1!
farbe = v1.get("farbe")
print("farbe of v1 is", farbe)

but its still the same NameError like before

Comment: I think you should open a thread at blenderastists.org to discuss your issues. btw. You still do not add " around your farbe.